# How to lock-free update in-memory storage across threads in Rust?

Tags: rust

I am accessing multiple external APIs and fetch data periodically. I store the results in-memory and serve them over REST endpoints.

I am using `Arc` and `Mutex` to pass access to the storage across threads:

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let store = Arc::new(Mutex::new(store::Store::default()));

    let server_handle = start_server(store.clone());
    let fetch_a = start_fetch_a(store.clone());
    let fetch_b = start_fetch_b(store.clone());


    let _ = tokio::join!(server_handle.await, fetch_a.await(), fetch_b.await());
}
```

The functions `fetch_a` and `fetch_b` update the storage via requesting a `lock()` and inserting data. This blocks the server threads for a short period.

What I would like to have is no blocking, maybe a cache which the server routes access, and the `fetch_a` and `fetch_b` functions update the cache. How would one go about this issue?

Comment: A [`RwLock`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.RwLock.html) might suffice?

Comment: AFAIK, if a writer acquires the lock, the readers are blocked and waiting to read. So in this scenario, I don't gain anything.

Comment: It sounds a little like you're keeping the lock too long on the write side, there is no non UB way to read data while it's being written.

Comment: @ohboy21, if the type of `Store` is complex, then a `RwLock` is the best you can do. It might be beneficial to re-create `Store` in the writer, and then simply swap the value out while holding the write-lock for a very short period of time, instead of holding the lock while mutating the existing value in a complex operation. If the type is simple, you can use unsynchronized Atomics, and endure the hilarity that will ensue

Comment: ^ following that principle can be done atomically even with complex types using the [arc-swap](https://crates.io/crates/arc-swap) crate.